# Is it possible to run a asp.net mvc(.net 3.5) website in 1and1 hosting machine?

Tags: web-hosting

I am using 1&1 MS Developer Package, it supports asp.net 2.0 only. Is it possible to run asp.net 3.5 web? If not is there any stable hosting company to recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried including assemblies from 3.5, that you need in your application. AFAIK CLR normally checks DLLs in this order:

- application bin folder
- GAC

So if you'd include those assemblies you need in your bin it may work. It depends if any of the capabilities should also be supported by .net machine (or applicationHost or any other) configuration. In this case you're wingless. ;)

Comment: That's correct--you can use *most* of the 3.5 libraries. But there are some things you'll miss out on, like the new C# features, since that requires the newer compiler and that needs to be 'installed' on the server. So, any libraries like System.Linq won't be very useful until 3.5 is fully installed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem than you...I bought the package a year ago, I thought that they would have .NET 3.5 installed when I would have finish developping my website and it makes at least a year and a half now and this is not done yet...I am really disappointed by 1AND1...they are supposed to be one of the major hosting company and they have great price but they are so outdated compared to the others. I have contacted them and they told me that they don't plan to upgrade for the moment...

I took a look at some hosting companies, I found www.discoutasp.net but if you need a SQL database, you have to pay it in extra, then I found http://webhost4life.com/ they have really good prices, you have a SQL Database by default, ASP.NET 3.5, MVC 1.0 framework.

I did not transfer my hosting for the moment but I am pretty sure I will go with them.

Hope it helps!

Charles

Comment: While I haven't used them personally yet everything about webhost4life seems fantastic from their product offerings to their pricing. There was a question on stackoverflow about best ASP.NET hosts and this name was brought up by more than 1 commenter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for the ASP.NET 3.5 hosting, some of the web hostings can support, such as ixwebhosting, easycgi, webhost4life, Lunarpages .. I didn\'t host my website with 1and1 before, looks like webhost4life is a good option, but you can check http://servefault.com/ASPNET-MVC-Web-Hosting\">more information further first

Cheers